# How to get partitions for kafka topic using kafka-python?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

I would like to get the offset for a kafka topic.
I tried the code mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685608/2762279 but it isn't working.

I found that getting the offsets requires a partition parameter `end_offsets(partitions)`.
So, I used the underlying code to find the partitions for the topic however it returns a `None`.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

topic = 'TOPIC'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    topic,
    bootstrap_servers=['IP:PORT'],
    client_id = 'CLI',
    group_id='GR',
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    consumer_timeout_ms=10000)

print(consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic))
```

Should i call a method (some sort of connect) before getting the partitions?

Comment: Is your intent to find the last offset of a partition?

Comment: @void Yes, i want to find the last offset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get latest offset for a partition for a kafka topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432326/how-to-get-latest-offset-for-a-partition-for-a-kafka-topic)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685608/2408270 check this out OP